I can't make IPV6 NFS to work
I've boxes running 24.04.1 LTS fully up to date.
I use Avahi/mdns for my name resolution/discovery and DHCP from my ISP router both on IPV4 and IPV6. The NFS server and client are set up to use NFS V4.
Everything works fine except ™ for NFS mount using IPV6.
When I try to mount an nfs share on my client using IPV6 addresses I get :
# mount -t nfs -vvvv server.local:/home/user /mnt
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Dec  1 17:47:27 2024
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=ivp6serveraddress%3,clientaddr=<IPV6-client-addr>:6070'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,minorversion=1,addr=ivp6serveraddress%3,clientaddr=<IPV6-client-addr>:6070'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=ivp6serveraddress%3,clientaddr=<IPV6-client-addr>:6070'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=ivp6serveraddress%3'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying ivp6serveraddress%3 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying ivp6serveraddress%3 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 60349
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=serveurIPV4Addr'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying serveurIPV4Addr prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying serveurIPV4Addr prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 36855
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified for /mnt

When I try using IPV4 I get immediate mount under /mnt.
At first I thought it was an UFW problem on the server side but the behavior is the same
with UFW disabled.
My exports file on the server gives :
# exportfs
/home/user      2xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64
/home/user      192.168.0.0/24

I've spent a lot of time trying to debug this but as I was not trained to IPV6 before retiring (I'm too old) I cant find what is wrong/what to do to make it run.
So all the help you will gave will be appreciated.
Have a nice and bright day !

I'm not very familiar with NTS or anything but are you putting the address between brackets? e.g. [2606:4700:4700::1111]:53 ?

Thank you for your answer, but according to the exportfs man page, the brackets should not be placed here. I will try it, just to be sure.

Tried it. Does not work.

@GeorgesGiralt Would you add output of: sudo ss -l -6 -p; sudo ss -l -4 -p   , ping -c 4 server.local , avahi-resolve -4 -n server.local; avahi-resolve -6 -n server.local

Hi User.dz, I'm very very reluctant to publish the information you ask. But since my first post, I was able to make the NFS mount to work. The mount command when it get the IPV6 address get with it the interface to use (the %3 in the above text)  and is unable to remove it, making the mount call to fail.

The previous comment was cut too soon..
If you copy the mount command, edit it to remove the %3 and use it, the mount complete instantly. The bug lies in the way the mount command get the IPV6 server address and use it.
I don't know how to file a bug report but this is a bug.
Thanks for your response and enjoy Christmas time !
